# I like to remove the empty lines and white-spaces from my query results compare two result?

Tags: c#, oracle, string-comparison

I like to remove the empty lines and  white-spaces from my query results and using below code, where I am doing wrong? I have 2 connections that getting the result from different users. I used get.ddl to get procedure definitions and trying to compare them if they are same or not.Belows are my 2 procedures ddl result and they are same, but because of the empty lines results shows **not same**.

**First query result:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "HELL_" 
as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello!');
end;
```

**second query result(Which has empty lines)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "HELL_" 
as

begin

  dbms_output.put_line('Hello!');

end;
```

**my Code**

```
            string result1 = "";
            string result2 = "";

            using (OracleConnection conn1 = new OracleConnection(oradb1))
            {
                conn1.Open();

                using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand("select REGEXP_REPLACE(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE','HELL_'),('user1...'),'', 1, 0, 'i') from dual", conn1))
                {
                    result1 = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 

                }
            }
            using (OracleConnection conn2 = new OracleConnection(oradb2))
            {
                conn2.Open();

                using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand("select REGEXP_REPLACE(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE','HELL_'),('user2...'),'', 1, 0, 'i') from dual", conn2))
                {
                    result2 = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                }
            }

            var lines1 = result1.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0).Select(l => l.Trim());
            var lines2 = result2.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0).Select(l => l.Trim());



            if (lines1.SequenceEqual(lines2)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("same");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("not same");
            }
```

Comment: These are not "queries".  If you want to compare source code, use the USER_SOURCE views.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to delete empty lines(the lines that contain only new line character) in the result set:

Lets create a simple stored procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure Some_Proc
  2  is
  3  
  4  
  5  begin
  6  
  7    null;
  8  
  9  
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created
```

By querying `user_source view`, or using `dbms_metadata` we will get the following result:

```
select t.text
  from all_source t
where name = upper('some_proc')
```

result:

```
Text 
-------------------------------
procedure Some_Proc
is


begin


  null;


end;
```

1. Get rid of *empty lines* when you are querying `[dba][user][all]_source` view(s) using
   `rtrim()` function:

   ```
   select t.text
     from all_source t
    where name = upper('some_proc')
      and rtrim(t.text, chr(10)) is not null
   ```

   result:

   ```
   Text 
   -------------------
   procedure Some_Proc
   is
   begin
     null;
   end;
   ```
2. Get rid of *empty lines* in the result data returning by `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()`
   function by using `regexp_replace()` regular expression function:

   ```
   select regexp_replace(
                         dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'PROCEDURE'
                                               ,'SOME_PROC'
                                               , user
                                              )
                        , '('||chr(10)||'){2,}', chr(10)
                        ) as res
     from dual
   ```

   result:

   ```
   Res 
   ------------------------
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "HR"."SOME_PROC" 
   is
   begin
     null;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Bear in mind that with some OSes the newline is in fact two characters, a line feed (ASCII 10) and a carriage return (ASCII 13) .

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to consider files to be equal even though one has blank lines added.  My suggestion is that if you want blank lines to be ignored you should make a pass through the collections you're creating (lines1 and lines2) to eliminate zero-length lines.

Share and enjoy.